# How to fill missing values with previous values in select statement

Tags: sql-server

My table:

```
ID  Name  code  date      division  product   
1   xyz   1     20121212  abc       pro
          2     20131212  pqr       pro2
          3     20140422  lmn       pro3
```

I want to use select statement that could generate result:

```
ID  Name  code  date      division  product   
1   xyz   1     20121212  abc       pro
1   xyz   2     20131212  pqr       pro2
1   xyz   3     20140422  lmn       pro3
```

How could I do it ?

Comment: is there null values under ID, Name columns?

Comment: What if ID also have another value (say `2`) in another row?  then which one do you need to choose for filling null/empty rows ?

Comment: How is "previous" defined? In order of code? Date? Also what version of SQL Server?

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2014. There are no values under ID and Name, but I can't use NULL. There is no order actually data is in flat file for single participant. so somethings are common that's why I need to select the same name and id for all the rest column records.

Comment: You can use grouping when showing this in a report, for example using SQL Server Reporting Services. You cannot do this using T-SQL.

Comment: can it be done in some other sql language ? if yes then how ??

Answer (score 0):

Hi Thanks All for Answering I got the solution it seems something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID, t1.Name, t2.code, t2.date, t2.division, t2.product
FROM  table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2 WHERE t1.ID IS NOT NULL
```

using cross join and applying condition did the work :D